# Renewing letsencrypt certificate fails due to DNS A/AAAA records

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, linode

I have a Next.JS app hosted on Linode using nginx and pm2.

When I try to renew my certificate I run the following command:

```
sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/project -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

However this results in some challenges failing, specifically this error:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/tdrjf7xqYmTEcZUGxfpDQ179XVA55wcaV6de30nMlJE
   [2a01:7e01::f03c:92ff:fefb:29]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1 (Ub"

   Domain: www.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AlIotwMFT_m-mlPvlg30Ya2r4sFm6qxLjZxjnBmmOJA
   [2a01:7e01::f03c:92ff:fefb:29]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1 (Ub"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Now I am not sure if I have to configure something else in Linode or something else. Anyone know what I need to do?

Here is my nginx setup:

```
# redirect http to https
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  # listen on *:443 -> ssl; instead of *:80
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  location / {
    # reverse proxy for next server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    # we need to remove this 404 handling
    # because next's _next folder and own handling
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your title says `due to DNS A/AAAA records` but you did not mention that at all in your question? Is DNS involved or not?

Comment: Try adding `root /var/www/project;` to the `location /.well-known` block.

Comment: Don'tPanic The error message is in the question body.
@RichardSmith Thanks! That did the tricks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go and check your nginx sites-available files.

In the server_name line we always append subdomains(if any) and the parent domain.

> Parent domain: example.com

> Subdomain: api.example.com

In your case, you only need to renew the certificate for example.com and not [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Also, if you have a different host who's managing the domain, example.com and you have an app on a different server say digitalocean droplet(as was my case) kindly affirm that example.com DNS points to your server.

Similarly, in your server, assert that the DNS records for A and NS for domain example.com is configured to point to your droplet.